# Python Script not running ".sh" file

Tags: python, execute

I have written a simple python script that is supposed to run a "sh" file when it is executed. 
The problem is, that the script runs but it does not start the ".sh" file. When I execute the ".sh" file manually using "puffy" it does the job, but not when I use my python script. So, what do I have to change in my script in order for it to work?

I will post the methods below so you could get a better idea. I also am using python 3.3.5, Oracle Linux 6.8.

The method that calls the ".sh" file, I have used Popen.

```
def runPrestage2Stage(self):
    import time
    time.sleep(60)
    reload(Queries)
    if "FINISHED" in Queries.statusS2S:
        #run batch file
        p = Popen(["sh", "/u01/app/Oracle_ODI_11/oracledi/agent/bin/start_prestage2stage_simple.sh"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
        stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
        print("Prestage2Stage has started")
    elif 'ERROR' in Queries.statusS2S:
        print("Can not start Prestage Converter, please check runtime status of Stage Converter")
    else:
        print("Prestage2Stage Converter cannot be started")
```

Part of main method, that calls the method runPRestage2Stage.

```
DailyLoadsAutomation.DailyLoads.runPrestage2Stage(self)
    load_paraprak_prestage = True
    count2 = 0
    while load_paraprak_prestage:
        reload(Queries)
        sleep(300) #waits 300 seconds (5 minutes) and re-checks load status.
        if "FINISHED" in Queries.statusPreStage:
            load_paraprak_prestage = False
        else:
            load_paraprak_prestage = True
            if count2 == 8:
                import sys
                sys.exit()
            else:
                count2 += 1
print("PreStage is finished")
```

When I run the script,

It will print "Prestage2Stage has started", and "Prestage is finished", as it is supposed to, but It will not run the ".sh" file.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: How do you know it's not running the script?

Comment: I know it because the ".sh" file runs a job in ORACLE ODI (data integrator) and I can check the runtime status of that job in the DB. But when I executed the python script it did not change the runtime status of the ODI job to "running" as it was supposed to if the "sh" script ran.

Comment: Try running `['sh', '-x´, script]` i.e. add the `-x` option to get detailed debugging output.

Answer (score 0):

usually it is related to user rights or errors in path. You can replace you .sh script with some simple one like "echo "I am running"" and see if it can be accessed and executed. If it is under linux, I hope you are are giving execution rights to you sh script via chmod.

Comment: I'm very new to Linux so I need some clarifications on this. I used to run the ".sh" file using the terminal window and it did work. So this means the ".sh" file has execution rights or doesn't it?

Comment: If you run `sh filename` you only need read access to `filename`. If you have a valid shebang line (`#!/bin/sh`) and execute permission, you can run it with `./filename` but that's not what the OP is attempting here.

Comment: Execute permission means you have done `chmod +x` but as detailed in my previous comment, that's not the issue here.

Comment: When I execute the .sh file using the terminal window I just change the directory where the file is located and type ./start_prestage2stage_simple.sh and it will run. But the same thing is not happening when I use python script.

Answer (score 0):

You can run sh file by importing os module like this:

```
import os 
os.system('sh filename.sh')
```

Comment: Do I have to specify a path where the ".sh" file is located like I did in my example?

Comment: yes, you need to locate your sh file, unless it is at the same place where your python file.